# How to update kernel values in a convolutional layer during backward pass?

Tags: conv-neural-network, convolution, backpropagation

I started coding backpropagation for a simple convnet and had some troubles understanding the algorithm. I do get the idea of weight update based on gradients, but because the filter kernel parameters are shared across the field, I am not sure hot to jointly process all gradients that should contribute to the update.
How do I update the kernel values during backprop in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Gradients flow back to where they came from. So any weight that contributed to an output gets updated with gradients from that output. In the case of a conv layer, a weight that contributed to multiple outputs get updated multiple times, once for each output. The updates are summed.

Answer (score -1):

Updating the weights (kernels) through the convolutional layer is done by convolving the (l+1) delta with the (l+1) weight. This gives the delta for updating the kernel. For a detailed explanation, check out [deepgrid](http://www.jefkine.com/general/2016/09/05/backpropagation-in-convolutional-neural-networks/).
Also, check out the github repo on CNN [here](https://github.com/tj27-vkr/CNN-from-sratch), that implements backpropagation and updating the weights on a simple CNN.

Comment: Hi. We're looking for answers which can "stand alone" without requiring external links (links can die!). Could you please edit your answer to include the essential information in these links? Thanks.